# Clicking a link will provide an additional text box/input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The current design of one of page of my application is such that an input field "email" is there where we can provide multiple email addresses separated by comma. user can provide the email ids and clicking on "update" button will update the database.

I have to redesign this in such a way that now for each email addresses,  i have to provide a separate input field. There should be a link (say "add More") on the right of the existing "email" input field. clicking on this link "add More" will give you a new textbox/input filed below the existing "email" field. clicking again on the link will give you an additional input field where i can provide the email id. similarly, we can add a maximum of 10 input fields for separate email ids.

Could you please tell me how to design this. And how we will provide validation that we cannot add further input field after 10.

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: You could keep adding all of the input fields into one container until the number of children of that container is 10. You could use the .children property for determining each of the children. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children You can also .createElement() and .appendChild() to dynamically keep adding input fields

Comment: Also, with an add more option, you may want to offer an option to remove the last one in case someone makes a mistake.

Comment: yes. i also want a delete button image on the right side of each textbox which will delete that particular input field. how can we do this

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` (or any jQuery utility functions) to add new HTML elements:

```
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="emails">
    <div><input type="text" /><button onclick="del(this)">Delete</button></div>
</div>

var numAdd = 1;
var add = function() {
    if (numAdd >= 10) return;
    $('#emails').append('<div><input type="text" /><button onclick="del(this)">Delete</button></div>');
    numAdd++;
};

var del = function(btn) {
    $(btn).parent().remove();
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P5QJ/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. also, i also want a delete button image on the right side of each textbox which will delete that particular input field. how can we do this using JS/ajax. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `.remove()` to delete an element like in the updated answer